# How to center tables with 100% width?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a horizontal "navigation bar" of some sort, and can't figure out how to center the table I'm using. Is the table the right way to do it and if so, how would I go about centering it properly?

This is my CSS

```css
table.topbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #efc700;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

a.topbar {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And this is my HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Week One</title>
    <link href="./style_home.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Chettan|Montserrat|Oswald|ZCOOL+XiaoWei" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topbar">
      <table class="topbar">
        <tr>
          <td><a class="topbar">Home</a></td>
          <td><a class="topbar">About</a></td>
          <td><a class="topbar">Contact</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Image of the result (It's not centered properly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6xJg.png)

Comment: add some code that you have tried

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't post images of code - post the actual code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question.  Also don't use a table for anything other than tabular data - a navigation list is not tabular data so do not use a table

Comment: code should be included as text and not image. but how are you going to center something that is taking 100% of the space? If your object will take less than 100% of the space then you can decide what to do with margins (alignment)

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mmm... you can use unordered list with css too . Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float:left;
  width: 33.3%;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) library. There are lots of table templates are given. You can use one of them. I also put code on fiddle you check link below. Hope it will help.

```
 [2]: https://jsfiddle.net/anshulsharma989/ykw0mj93/1/
```

**Edit: Core HTML and CSS implementation.**

**HTML CODE:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First</th>
            <th>Last</th>
            <th>Handle</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <th>1</th>
         <td>Mark</td>
         <td>Otto</td>
         <td>@mdo</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </body>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.table {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: I'm new to HTML so I'm staying away from libraries for now.

Comment: @Keveran I have updated the answer for core HTML and CSS. You can check now.

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple by using `Flex` just add below **CSS** will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
tr {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```